# Call a function while in a loop (Common Lisp)

Tags: function, loops, common-lisp, clisp

I am making a console Lisp survival game and I am trying to add a function where until a = b, show "." every second. Then, when a = b, set a "hurt" variable to true, and if/when that variable is true, subtract "health" by 1 until the "use-medkit" function is invoked by the user and the "hurt" variable is set false and you exit both loops.

The problem I am having is when I am prompted to use the "use-medkit" function and I type it in, it doesn't evaluate anything that I input and keeps subtracting 1 from "health". How can I call a user-inputted function while a loop is running?

Here is my code:

```
(setq a (random 11)) ; Random from 0 - 10
(setq b (random 11)) ; ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
(setq hurt 0)
(setq repair 0)
(setq health 999)

(defun use-medkit () 
    (setq repair 1))

(defun get-hurt ()
    (loop
        (progn 
            (setq a (random 11))
            (setq b (random 11))
            (progn  
                (princ ".")
                (sleep 1)))

        (if (eq a b) (progn     
                        (setq hurt 1)
                        (when (eq hurt 1) (progn        
                                            (format t "~%You are hurt!~%You will lose 1 hp every 10 seconds~%~%Type use-medkit to stop the bleeding~%")
                                            (loop
                                                (progn 
                                                    (- 1 health)
                                                    (sleep 10))
                                                    ;(format t "health: ~A~%" health)
                                                (when (eq repair 1) (progn 
                                                                 (return "You stopped the bleeding") (setq hurt 0) (setq repair 0))))))))))
```

Comment: a good start would be to format your code in such a way, that it is readable for humans. Currently it is hard to read.

Comment: the code actually shows that you still struggle with basic Lisp programming. Here is a good introductory book, available as a free PDF download or as a printed book: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/index.html

Comment: This error is in some sense straightforward and in another sense a little subtle. Lisp is single threaded (strictly speaking some implications support multiple threads but I don’t think you want that). You’re program spends all it’s time either doing things like making random numbers or printing or sleeping. There is no point where it stops to allow anything else to run. You can’t run `use-medkit` until this function has finished, by which point it’s too late. Lisp has no event loop by default.

Comment: Know that in CL `setq` does not define variables so what will happen if `a` does not exist is undefined. Use `defparameter` or `defvar` and make use of the `*earmuff*` convention to not end up in an impossible situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a program can’t do two things at once. In particular if you’re busy printing dots, sleeping and subtracting 1 from 999 then you won’t pause to see if there’s another command coming.

Unfortunately solving this problem is hard. The nicest solution in a terminal would probably use something like ncurses. Additionally there is no standard way to control input buffering. In lieu of that, here is a simple way you can do a bit of concurrency and some prompts. You might want to use a proper async library instead.

```
(defun maybe-read (input-stream recording-stream)
  (when (listen input-stream)
    (let ((char (read-char input-stream)))
      (if (char= char #\Newline)
         t
         (progn (write-char char recording-stream) (maybe-read))))))

(defun make-partial-reader (input-stream)
  (list input-stream (make-string-output-stream)))
(defun partial-read (reader)
  (when (apply #'maybe-read reader)
     (get-output-stream-string (second reader))))

(defun how-long-until (time)
  (let ((gap
          (/ (- time (get-internal-run-time)) internal-time-units-per-second)))
    (cond ((< gap 0) (values 0 :late))
          ((<= gap 0.001) (values 0 :now))
          (T (values (- gap 0.001) :soon)))))
(defun sleep-until (time)
  (multiple-value-bind (span type)
        (how-long-until time)
    (when (> span 60) (warn “long wait!”)
    (case type
      (:late nil)
      (:now t)
      (:soon
        (sleep span)
        (unless (sleep-until time) (warn “poor timekeeping”))
        t))))
(defmacro with-prompt-and-scheduler ((schedule) (line &optional (input *standard-input*)) &body handle-line-input)
  (let ((reader (gensym)) (insched (gensym)))
    `(let ((,reader (make-partial-reader ,input) (,insched)))
        (flet ((,schedule (in fun &aux (at (+ (get-internal-run-time) (* in internal-time-units-per-second))))
                 (if (null ,insched) (push (cons at fun) schedule)
                    (loop for s on ,insched
                          for ((at2) . y) = s
                      if (< at at2)
                       do (psetf (car s) (cons at fun)
                                 (cdr s) (cons (car s) (cdr s)))
                          (finish-loop)
                      unless y do (setf (cdr s) (acons at fun nil)) (finish-loop)))))
         (loop
           (if ,insched
               (let ((,insched (pop ,insched)))
                 (when (sleep-until (car ,insched))
                   (let ((,line (partial-read ,reader)))
                     (when ,line ,@handle-line-input)))
                 (funcall (cdr ,insched)))
               (let ((,line (concatenate 'string (get-output-stream-string (second ,reader)) (read-line (first ,reader)))))
                 ,@handle-line))))))))
```

And then you could use it like:

```
(let ((count 0))
  (with-prompt-and-scheduler (schedule) (line)
    (let ((n (read-from-string line)))
      (when (realp n)
        (schedule n (let ((x (incf count))) (lambda () (format t "Ding ~a ~a~%" x count) (finish-output))))))))
```

And after running that input 10, then on the next line 5. If you do that quickly you’ll get:

```
Ding 2 2
Ding 1 2
```

With the first line appearing after 5 seconds and the second after 10. If you are slow you should get:

```
Ding 1 1
Ding 2 2
```

With the first line coming 10 seconds after you enter 10 and the second line coming 5 seconds after you enter 5.

Hopefully this can give you an idea of how to make a program seem to do two things at once.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about making it simpler and approaching it at a different angle, but this really helps!

Comment: I would recommend you first learn some more Lisp and then use something like cl-async and ncurses. Or that you just try to avoid multiple things happening at once.